# Recursion in console, batch calculation (JS)

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await, console, batch-processing

I have a website which calculates various aspects of musical intonation. I would like to do a batch calculation in the console, but it seems that recursion is causing a problem because it needs to run a function (maybe?). I have a very large array called `ratio` which holds many numerators and denominators. I would like to inject them into pre-existing variables called `inputNum` and `inputDen` and then run the underlying JS function `doCalc()` that I have coded on the site, which takes the inputs and does various calculations with them. The result outputs into some `div` fields on the page, which I just want to print in the log (to copy and paste into a spreadsheet). My code looks like this so far, after defining the large array of fractions `ratio`.

```
var i = 0;                  

async function loop() {   
    inputNum = ratio[i][0];
    inputDen = ratio[i][1];
    await doCalc();       
    console.log(document.getElementById("notationOutput").innerHTML+" "+document.getElementById("noteName").innerHTML);   
    i++;                   
    if (i < ratio.length) {           
        loop();             
    }                      
}

loop();
```

Since it takes a non-negligible amount of time to do the calculation before displaying the results (I assume), I thought an async function would be the way to go, but I don't seem to be implementing it correctly. Otherwise, I would have done it with a simple while loop, but apparently `setTimeout` won't work in that case.

Comment: what's `doCalc();`? how do you know you're not implementing it correctly - what behavior is it displaying (any errors)? you mention `setTimeout` but don't use it anywhere in this code - is it used in `doCalc()`?

Comment: @Klaycon sorry `myLoop` was a typo, fixed. `doCalc()` is simply the various operations the website does on the variables `inputNum` and `inputDen`. Currently, all that happens is it does the calculation for the first element in `ratio`, then displays `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}`. It needs to do this operation 933 times (`ratio.length`) not just once.

Comment: I recommend you put the code of `doCalc()` in the question because your problem is almost certainly in there (i'm assuming it sets `(#notationOutput).innerHTML` and stuff). It also helps add context so we may identify a better solution for you than this recursive approach. If it has a `setTimeout` it is very likely the culprit.

Comment: That calculation would have to be horrendously complex for 933 instances to actually be a bottleneck.  As Klaycon said, please show us the code.  And show us some sample data too, ideally.  (Not 933 of them please!  Five or six should be plenty.)

Comment: This is what I suspected. I hesitate to include code for `doCalc`, mostly because I don't know what to include necessarily without being too verbose, as it calls various modules defined over hundreds of lines. But the calculations are basically simple arithmetic operations, some prime factorisations (of small numbers). When I use the site, it is very quick (you can see at https://www.plainsound.org/HEJI/, just click some of the buttons on the "notation palette" input area, you can see how fast it is).

Comment: What is odd, is that I can call single instances. For instance, if I take it out of the function and just set the values, call the `doCalc` function, then log in the console, everything works fine for a single case.

Comment: I do happen to get the result but also a message ´< undefined´ underneath ... not sure what that might mean or even refer to... I am new to trying to automate these things.

Comment: At a glance, the problem is fundamental.  You're using code designed to asynchronously modify the DOM and trying to turn it into a mostly-synchronous logging function.  I may be missing something, but it looks as though a fundamental redesign would be necessary.  For instance, if `doCalc` took `numerator` and `denominator` arguments and then returned an object with `notationOutput` and `noteName` properties, this would be straightforward.  But that would involve revamping a lot of DOM code.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I wonder. For instance, there are event listeners that wait for changes to the numerator and denominator made by a user interacting with the program (number input boxes). When it registers a change, it automatically initiates `doCalc` to make the calculations. However, when I modify the num and den in the console by simply giving them values, I see them change in the number boxes BUT `doCalc` does not trigger. Almost as if the event listeners do not recognise the change made in the console. Is this the sort of thing you are talking about?

Comment: Not really.  What I'm discussing is the fact that you're trying to use the changes to the DOM in a real-time calculation of values.  This should be possible, if slow.  But it is extremely awkward.  If instead your DOM code and console code depended on pure calculation functions, this would be trivial to do.  I'll add an answer to demonstrate the concept, but a real implementation would involve a lot of changes to your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, what you want to do should be possible, but it's a pretty awful way of writing this sort of functionality.  Depending upon the DOM and global variables to do your work is pretty nasty.

If we start with something like this:

```js
const doCalc = () => {
  const num = Number (document .getElementById ('numerator') .value)
  const den = Number (document .getElementById ('denominator') .value)
  // do some real work here
  const notationOutput = `${num}/${den}`
  const noteName = `${num}--${den}`
  document .getElementById ("notationOutput") .innerHTML = notationOutput
  document .getElementById ("noteName") .innerHTML = noteName
}

document .getElementById ('numerator') .onchange = doCalc
document .getElementById ('denominator') .onchange = doCalc

const logAll = (ratios) =>
  ratios 
    .forEach (([num, den]) => {
       document .getElementById ('numerator') .value = String (num)
       document .getElementById ('denominator') .value = String (den)
       doCalc()
       const notationOutput = document .getElementById ("notationOutput") .innerHTML
       const noteName = document .getElementById ("noteName") .innerHTML
       console.log(`${notationOutput} ${noteName}`)
    })

const ratios = [[5, 3], [7, 4], [3, 2], [13, 1]]

document.getElementById('batch') .onclick = (evt) => logAll (ratios)
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Numerator: <input id="numerator" /></label>
  <label>Denominator: <input id="denominator" /></lbael>
</p>
<p>Notation Output <span id="notationOutput"></span></p>
<p>Note Name <span id="noteName"></span></p>
<p><button id="batch">Run Batch</button></p>
```

---

We would eventually want to get to something like this:

```js
const doCalc = ([num, den]) => {
  // do some real work here
  return {
    notationOutput: `${num}/${den}`,
    noteName: `${num}--${den}`
  }
}

const change = (evt) => {
  const num = Number (document .getElementById ('numerator') .value)
  const den = Number (document .getElementById ('denominator') .value)
  const {notationOutput, noteName} = doCalc ([num, den])
  document .getElementById ("notationOutput") .innerHTML = notationOutput
  document .getElementById ("noteName") .innerHTML = noteName
}

document .getElementById ('numerator') .onchange = change
document .getElementById ('denominator') .onchange = change

const logAll = (ratios) =>
  ratios 
    .map (doCalc) 
    .forEach (
      ({notationOutput, noteName}) => console.log(`${notationOutput} ${noteName}`)
    )

const ratios = [[5, 3], [7, 4], [3, 2], [13, 1]]

document.getElementById('batch') .onclick = (evt) => logAll (ratios)
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Numerator: <input id="numerator" /></label>
  <label>Denominator: <input id="denominator" /></lbael>
</p>
<p>Notation Output <span id="notationOutput"></span></p>
<p>Note Name <span id="noteName"></span></p>
<p><button id="batch">Run Batch</button></p>
```

The big difference is that the calculation is done without worrying about the DOM.  It is a pure function, and the code that uses it can use it to write to the console or to update the DOM.

---

Note also, though, that my first block does work.  It's possible that if you changed your loop to this sort of structure that it will work for you.  But it would then forever remain code difficult to test, difficult to extend, and difficult to understand.

The second format is much simpler.

Comment: Wow thank you, this is bringing me closer for sure. I was able to modify your code to fit my situation, and it now loops the exact length of my ratio array (it was getting stuck before and looping infinitely before), but it seems to just log the result for the first element of `ratios` 934 times, rather than each of the 934 elements once. Can't see immediately why that might be the case, but taking a look now...

Comment: We are in business! Thank you for your detailed explanation and helpful example. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `await` to **loop()** calling which is being called inside `if` as below

```
var i = 0;                  

async function loop() {   
    inputNum = ratio[i][0];
    inputDen = ratio[i][1];
    await doCalc();       
    console.log(document.getElementById("notationOutput").innerHTML+" "+document.getElementById("noteName").innerHTML);   
    i++;                   
    if (i < ratio.length) {           
        await loop();  // Adding await here           
    }                      
}

loop();
```

(or)

As a self invocation call

```
(async function loop() {   
    inputNum = ratio[i][0];
    inputDen = ratio[i][1];
    await doCalc();       
    console.log(document.getElementById("notationOutput").innerHTML+" "+document.getElementById("noteName").innerHTML);   
    i++;                   
    if (i < ratio.length) {           
        await loop();  // Adding await here           
    }                      
})();
```

Similar examples for [your reference](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/09/14/asynchronous-recursion.html) - Scroll to the end for `async`/`await` **recursion** sample function.

Comment: Interesting, when I run the top code block it actually gave me results for the first two rows in the `ratio` array... but then seems to get stuck (endlessly incrementing, seems to repeatedly calculate the second row over and over)

Comment: Can you please try with 5-10 iterations for testing purpose once.

Comment: For [your reference](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/09/14/asynchronous-recursion.html). You can scroll to the end for similar `async`/`await` recursion example.

Comment: So if I make i < 10 to see the first 10 calculations, it logs the output for the first element in `ratio` then says: `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined} __proto__: Promise [[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled" [[PromiseValue]]: undefined`

Comment: Maybe, we need to revisit the logic in `doCalc()`. The recursion with `async`/`await` is absolutely possible as mentioned in my previous comments.